# Definite integral $ \int_0^{\infty}e^{-A\,x^m-B\,x^p}x^n(x-\alpha)^{\sigma}\,dx$ in terms of of special functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions

Working on asymptotic expansion of certain integrals, it appear the following family of integrals

$$F(m,p,n,\alpha,\sigma)=\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}e^{-A\,x^m-B\,x^p}x^n(x-\alpha)^{\sigma}\,dx$$

with $m,n,p\in\mathbb{N}$ , $m\neq p$ , $\alpha\in(0,\infty)$ and $\sigma\in[0,1)$. Also $A,B>0$.

I wonder if is possible write $F(m,p,n,\alpha)$ in a closed form in terms of (probably) special functions.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: What is $(x-\alpha)^\sigma$ for $x<\alpha$?

Comment: First of all, your function depends on $\sigma$ as well, so I will add it to the list of arguments. In general, I would derive differential equations for $F$ in the hope it will help. To start with, we could observe that $$ \frac{d}{d\alpha}F(m,p,n,\alpha, \sigma) = -\sigma F(m,p,n,\alpha, \sigma-1). $$ How about $d/dA$, $d/dB$, etc.?